# SDL_OpenAudioDevice with multiple devices

Tags: c++, linux, audio, sdl

I am currently writing an application that will output sound to 3 different audio devices. For that, I have installed 3 USB Audio Devices in my PC, all the same brand. I wanted to use SDL2 as output device (although I am open minded for other suggestions). I had a look at the documentation and it states as the first parameter (device):

> a UTF-8 string reported by SDL_GetAudioDeviceName(); see Remarks

Now I have written a sample program, that just lists the available devices:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
        std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        atexit( SDL_Quit );
        int count = SDL_GetNumAudioDevices(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
                std::cout << "Device " << i << ": " << SDL_GetAudioDeviceName(i, 0) << std::endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

It enumerates all available devices. The problem is, that all 3 devices will give me the same name:

```
Device 0: Internes Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958)
Device 1: C-Media Electronics, Inc. Audio Adapter
Device 2: C-Media Electronics, Inc. Audio Adapter
Device 3: C-Media Electronics, Inc. Audio Adapter
```

Is there any way to use something else (e.g. the USB Path) as the parameter or to make sure that I can open all 3 devices?

Comment: Can you clarify the initial problem statement? Is there an Init() or Get() function that you're calling that _only_ takes a device name as a parameter? If `SDL_GetAudioDeviceName()` takes an index to identify which device you want, that implies that other interfaces will also do so.If not, you may still be able to simply call the same Init() or Get() function, passing the same device name, and getting different handles/pointers/whatever back. But there isn't enough information here to be able to tell.

Comment: There is no function I have found that will utilize the indexing function. here is the overview of available audio functions: https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryAudio it only lists https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_OpenAudioDevice?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryAudio%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29 which takes only the device string as identifier.

Comment: Looking like an API shortcoming from where I'm sitting.  Which SDL audio driver/backend are you going through?  PulseAudio?  Might be able to poke the SDL maintainers to add an order-of-enumeration number prefix/postfix to the device names (eg "`2: C-Media Electronics, Inc. Audio Adapter`").

Comment: Yeah, kinda like [that](https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/open-specific-sound-device/24932) :)

Comment: Thats what Ive posted after no answer here :). A dev talked to me and he will patch SDL to adress this issue :)

Comment: https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/rev/5ce13990c5fb